# Word for imputing one's motives to another by putting them in their mouth (King Lear)

Tags: single-word-requests, shakespeare

I am looking for a word to replace "declares" in this paragraph analysing Edmund's betrayal of his brother in Shakespeare's King Lear:

> Edmund begins his quest for power by setting Edgar up as a traitor against their father, forging a letter of Edgar’s supposed ill will against him. In malicious irony, he attributes to his brother the very motives which drive him to his designs against Edgar, writing in his stead, “I begin to find an idle and fond bondage in the oppression of aged tyranny, who sways, not as it hath power, but as it is suffered” (1.2.50). Edmund **declares** in this way that he is willing to suffer his father’s tyranny no more.

Comment: In that last sentence, you'd just be repeating the idea already clearly expressed in the sentence that begins "In malicious irony..."

Comment: What's the source? Why do you want to replace *declares* specifically?

Comment: The source is a paper I'm writing on King Lear. I want to replace _declares_ because it doesn't seem like the right word. He isn't making a declaration, he's...making a subconscious allusion. A Freudian slip, if you will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responding to your comment, you could replace *declares* with

**demonstrates**

There is a term in psychology that could be related to your original request, but I don't see a simple way of working it into your existing sentence:

**projection**

1. The act of projecting or the condition of being projected.
2. The attribution of one's own attitudes, feelings, or suppositions to
   others.
3. The attribution of one's own attitudes, feelings, or desires to
   someone or something as a naive or unconscious defense against
   anxiety or guilt.

The American Heritage® Stedman's Medical Dictionary. Houghton Mifflin Company. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/projection

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought of using "projects" in the place of "declares," but it would work earlier to replace "attributes to." With that in place, I think "demonstrates" will work better.